# Sketch, how to find and replace "text style"

Tags: text, sketch-app, interface-design

I have a library file in Sketch and I need to replace a specific `text-style` with another one, in all the instances it is been used across the file.

Is there a way to *find and replace* the `text-style`?

Answer (score 1):

You have to select an instance of the text-style you want to change, apply your changes and in the text-style panel, choose <kbd>update text style</kbd>

[image: Update global text style]